# Which manufacturer makes these crystal units?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, crystal, ceramic

I'd like to identify the manufacturer of these crystal units. Apparently the first line contains the frequency information (8 MHz, 16 MHz...).

The second line starts with a small 'e' which is probably a manufacturer signature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@nanash1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/333139/nanash1) found it !

The small "e" mark is used on Automotive qualified crystals of Seiko Epson.

If you go to the following link: https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/car_electronics/

in Crystal 32kHz and Crystal MHz sections, you can get several condensed datasheets and some overviews of some series.

One example:
https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/crystal_unit/fa2016aa.html

Thank's a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Epson devices have an "e" on them, but almost all I've seen use a capital "E".

And ECS devices normally have the full "ECS".

The only match I can see is Abracon, who use e2 to denote temperature stability.  See this [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/af18/A700000008730941.pdf) for one of their units, where e2 means +/-20ppm over the range -20°C ~ +70°C.  However that is far from a definite match.

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing, see here: https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/crystal-units/1732283

Comment: The one on the bottom could possibly belong to the Seiko Epson [FA-238A](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2008192035_Seiko-Epson-X1E0003410031_C725712.pdf) series. lcsc has [pictures](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Crystals_Seiko-Epson-X1E0003410031_C725712.html) that look very close in terms of marking style.